# How to compile the generated AS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, compiler-construction

hope you can help me with this question.

So, I've been working for a while with Flex, and had the crazy idea to create pure AS project.

If I compile a Flex app with the -keep flag, the generated actionscript gets generated.

Do you guys know of a way to make it compile, without going trough the code and gluing it all together?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "gluing it all together"?

Answer (score 1):

Generated ActionScript is really only provided for reference; it's not really intended to be repurposed in that sense.  Indeed, if you even have any, you've most likely compiled your project already anyway (unless you got it from somewhere else), so one might ask why you'd want to compile the generated stuff rather than your own source -- but nonetheless, although I haven't actually tried it, you should be able to point the Flex compiler [mxmlc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html) at your generated source to compile it, provided you're able to get all your dependencies to line up (which may be what you mean by "gluing it all together").

Just a thought, although again, I haven't actually tried it, so your results may vary.  What is it you're trying to do, though?  Just curious. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Christian mentioned, the generated AS code is pretty much there to serve as a reference. Just for fun, I tried compiling it from the command line using mxmlc, but part of the problem with doing that is that the class files generated don't match the classes they represent. So, you'd need to start renaming a bunch of your class files so that compiling those could even work. Many of the other classes in Flex won't be compiled in either, for the same reason.

As an example, the project I tested this with, had only one mxml file of source code in it. The generated output was 45 files. I'm sure that if you really wanted to do this, and were willing to invest the time in cleaning things up you could. But I'm curious too - why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was just mere curiosity. I wanted to understand how the framework works and see how it merges it all together to make the final application, as I thought that the generated actionscript files were just a step in between the final SWF file, so I tought there should be a way for it to grab those files and generate the final application.

Eventually I would have tried to create a pure actionscript project just for the heck of it to see how complicated it was and what errors could happen when developing other stuff.

I know it sounds crazy, but I had some spare time, ha ha ha.